# How does Apple's ProMotion display technology affect visual performance?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, performance

I switched from a 16 inch M1 MacBook Pro to a 15 inch M2 MacBook Air and realized the Air lacks ProMotion. After comparing tasks like scrolling in (native) apps, or panning and zooming in Figma, I don't see a noticeable difference.

I thought the absence of ProMotion might be a dealbreaker before purchasing. Now I'm questioning its real-world impact.

Can anyone clarify the tangible benefits of ProMotion in everyday use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some people refresh rates above 30 Hz are subjective and for most above 60 Hz are subjective and tricky to measure. I can’t say anyone needs 120 Hz even if they can notice it. Gaming and flow are nice to have for the majority of people.

Once you’ve seen many many years of rendering or are subject to motion sickness from jitter or spend hours a day with animation tuning, the extra horsepower for the ProMotion is far more relevant when you run into other bottlenecks like encoding or decoding video, rendering scenes or doing VR work. Then I can say the extra power and money is well spent if you have the budget.

It would be interesting to hear your workflow on why you assumed it would be a dealbreaker. Perhaps you’ve been burned in the past not getting the absolute top - but the original M1 with the fewest cores can rip through incredibly smooth animation when the code is all properly tuned and you’re not swapping code off the silicon or running shaders in an emulation layer or worse on the CPU only. The M2 are even more silky smooth across many situations and everyone has had tons of time to optimize for the architecture. Only product not caring a whit for tuning or not being maintained is still janky on Apple Silicon this far into the transition.

Comment: Indeed this is probably one of those “if it’s not the best in class it’s not worth having kind of things”. I’ve been using it for a few more days and haven’t noticed anything significant other than a slight difference in animations on an HTML5 game.